# How to extract XYZ data from .pcap file

Tags: ros, vlp16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am a complete freshman on Linux, ROS so, don't be mad :). I have a Velodyne VLP16 and the list that I want to with this laser is:

1. Acquire raw data (.pcap)
2. Visualize it using 3D viewer
3. Extract XYZ and Intensity data from acquired raw data

What I accomplished so far is only No.2 using commands below (I downloaded .pcap file from velodyne website):

```
$ roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VPL16_points.launch pcap:=/home/soowon/Documents/County_Fair.pcap

$ rosrun velodyne_pointcloud cloud_node _calibration:=/home/soowon/catkin_ws/src/velodyne-master/velodyne_pointcloud/params/VLP16db.yaml

$ rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne

$ Add -> By topic -> /velodyne_points -> PointCloud2
```

By commands above, I was able to see pointcloud using RViz. Now here's my questions:

1. I followed tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E) to establish connection using command below,

   $ sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.100

   $ sudo route add 192.168.XX.YY eth0

however, according to wireshark, connection wasn't established at all.

2. Now I can see (gladly) the pointcloud, I really want to extract X,Y, and Z coordinates with intensity from .pcap file. I found some great sources to start (https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl), but I am not sure whether I can pull this off by myself :(

Any advice would be superb!! Thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227345/how-to-extract-xyz-data-from-.pcap-file/) by [Soowon](https://answers.ros.org/users/26008/soowon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-02-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-24**:
The `VPL16_points.launch` script will run the cloud nodelet for you, so the `rosrun velodyne_pointcloud cloud_node` is unnecessary.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-24**:
Since you seem to be able to view the point cloud, I am uncertain what your exact question is. Are you asking about how to do the connection? Or, are you wondering how to write a ROS node that processes the data?

**Comment by [siaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/28216/siaca/) on 2016-10-12**:
I would be really interested in the second question you mention.. how to write a ROS node that processes the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here is a fairly simple package](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_height_map) that processes Velodyne data into a height map.

The source code is here: https://github.com/jack-oquin/velodyne_height_map

Despite its simplicity, it's fairly robust at detecting obstacles, although it is sometimes subject to false positives due to things like overhanging tree branches.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2018-09-24**:
This package is only for Indigo! :(